# Change color of xml drawable icon

Tags: android, android-xml

Is there any way of setting a color to an icon drawable? So that the icon's color would be overwritten by my custom color ?

```
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon1"
  //set color to my icon here
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon2"
  //set color to my icon here
  />
```

Comment: No, You cannot set the custom colors to your icons. You only can change the background colors of your views . for this you can have two icons of different colors and set the desired icons according to its state.

Comment: You are looking for a color filter [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable)

Comment: from android 5.0 you can tint your resource see https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#DrawableTint

Comment: I know about color filter. But it is not possible to do it in xml. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 11):

You can use this snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/signup_checkbox_empty" android:tint="@color/turquoise" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/signup_checkbox_full" android:tint="@color/turquoise" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/signup_checkbox_empty" android:tint="@color/turquoise" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 5):

In `android L (5.0)` there is a `TINT` feature which allows to change the color of a `drawable icon`. You can check an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482489/what-is-new-in-drawable-tinting-in-android-l-developer-preview-compared-to-previ).

For earlier `APIs` you have to use `multiple drawables` with `selector` strategy

Answer (score 5):

Use the `tint` attribute on your image element (or whatever you use to show an image), for example:

```html
<ImageView  android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawable_resource_name"
            android:tint="@color/color_name"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
android:drawableTint="@color/icon_color"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `app:drawableTint="@color/yourColor"` in the xml instade `android:drawableTint="@color/yourColor"`. It has the backward compatibility.